# Read Json Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "2","teamname" : "Milan"}]}
```

How do i write the code to read the teamid and teamname so as to store them in seperate variables?

Please Help!

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: I suggest tagging with javascript (if this is the language), there is nothing jQuery specific here. JSON once parsed is just array collections and object collections - take a look at this - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_intro.asp - to see how they work.

Comment: @DannyStaple While there is nothing specifically jquery about this question, it's useful for potential answerer's that jquery is available as a tool to accomplish the OP's goals...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it is a JSON string, parse it...

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString);
```

Then work with the information

```
obj.TeamList[0].teamid;
obj.TeamList[0].teamname;
```

`TeamList` is an array so if you have more than one "team" you'll need to loop over them.

Answer (score 2):

You have an object containing an array `TeamList`, which has one object as its elements:

```
var tl = {"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "2","teamname" : "Milan"}]};

var id = tl.TeamList[0].teamid;
var name = tl.TeamList[0].teamname;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the example you have posted in contained as a string you can parse it like so with javascript...

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
```

you can then access your array like so...

```
jsonObject.TeamList
```

and each item in TeamList...

```
jsonObject.TeamList[i].teamid
jsonObject.TeamList[i].teamname
```

finally assuming you have one item in TeamList and making an attemp to directly answers you question...

```
var teamid = jsonObject.TeamList[0].teamid;
var teamname = jsonObject.TeamList[0].teamname;
```

hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

in which language? Basically after parsing using json you would do something like this on the result:

`result["TeamList"][0]["teamname"]` to get teamname and `result["TeamList"][0]["teamid"]` to get teamid.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use json_decode, like this :

```
$content = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "2","teamname" : "Milan"}]}';
$json = json_decode($content);
$obj = $json->{'TeamList'}[0];
print $obj->{'teamid'}."//".$obj->{'teamname'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You had tagged your question as jQuery? We're you wanting to display this information on a page?

Given some sample html:

```
<label>Team ID:</label>
<div id="teamid"></div>

<label>Team Name:</label>
<div id="teamname"></div>
```

And a little jquery:

```
var obj = {"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "2","teamname" : "Milan"}]};

$('#teamid').html(obj.TeamList[0].teamid);
$('#teamname').html(obj.TeamList[0].teamname);
```

Would allow you to accomplish this. As others have pointed out you would need to iterate over the collection if there were multiple teams.